# Number $3 + i$ is an image of a number $\sqrt{2} + 2\sqrt{2}*i$ turned around a point 0. Am I doing it right?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Number $3 + i$ is an image of a number $\sqrt{2} + 2\sqrt{2}*i$ turned around a point 0 by which angle?

So I check that $2\sqrt{2}*x=1 ->x= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$

Then: $\sqrt{2}*\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}$

$\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}=/=3$

So it is not an image of that number turned around a point 0 by any angle. Am I right?

Comment: Why are you solving the equation $2 \sqrt{2}  \times x = 1$?

Comment: Because I want to know the angle that It could be rotated.

Comment: I don't see why the solution of that equation has anything to do with the angle it could be rotated.

Comment: Rotation = multiplication by a number. Am I right?

Comment: Rotation **in the complex plane** is multiplication by a number **on the unit circle**, i.e. multiplication by a number $a+bi$ such that $a^2+b^2=1$.

Comment: So how do I check if one point is a rotation of another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong.  Convert both numbers to polar form $(re^{i\theta})$.  For both numbers $r=\sqrt{10}$, so one is a rotation of the other.  For the first number $\theta  =arctan(1/3)$, while for the second $\theta =arctan(2)$.  Look up the angles to get the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation in the complex plane is multiplication by a number on the unit circle, i.e. multiplication by a number of the form $a+bi$ such that $a^2+b^2=1$.

The angle of that rotation can be computed using inverse trig functions, for example, $\tan^{-1}(b/a)$ if $a > 0$.

So the equation you should be trying to solve is
$$(3+i) \cdot (a+bi) = \sqrt{2} + 2 \sqrt{2} \, i
$$